# How to Change String Data in Dataframe to Number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataset of 10,000. These data are from UCI Machine Learning Repository Census Income.

Anyway, the point is that I want to change string data to  data. I want to run a naive bayes classification, but I need to use number.

Basically:

```
State-gov = 1
Self-emp-not-inc = 2
Private = 3
```

Dataframe:

```
          age          workclass   fnlwgt  ...  hours-per-week   native-country  income
    0      39          State-gov    77516  ...              40    United-States   <=50K
    1      50   Self-emp-not-inc    83311  ...              13    United-States   <=50K
    2      38            Private   215646  ...              40    United-States   <=50K
    3      53            Private   234721  ...              40    United-States   <=50K
    4      28            Private   338409  ...              40             Cuba   <=50K
```

Note: These are only 5 of 10,000 data.

Comment: You could look into [Label Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or [One Hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) using the `sklearn` package.

Answer (score 1):

Most data sciency way would be to use pandas' `dtype="category"`

```
df["workclass"] = df["workclass"].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if you can find what you want [here](https://datatofish.com/string-to-integer-dataframe/)

### (1) The astype(int) method:

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].astype(int)
```

### (2) The to_numeric method:

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DataFrame Column'])
```

Example :

```
import pandas as pd

Data = {'Product': ['AAA','BBB'],
          'Price': ['210','250']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

### Or maybe do you need to replace those string with [Dataframe.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

df['DataFrame Column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['DataFrame Column'])